# Принцип единственной ответственности

Tags: c#, solid

Первый принцип SOLID гласит что каждый класс выполняет лишь одну задачу. Я понимаю это так. Например есть у нас класс для работы с базой данных. В этот класс входят функции по отправке значений с ответом и без, для получения данных и т.д. И значит этот класс должен работать только с бд. А если мы добавим к примеру функцию парсинга из txt файла то это уже не соблюдение принципа. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: класс для работы с базой данных, сколько в нем будет строк кода? если 500 - то это явно не класс с единой ответственностью, а швейцарский нож.

Comment: ВЫ все правильно понимаете, но забываете об остальных принципах, которые требуют так же определенные вещи. Т.е. да класс должен выполнять строго направленые функции, но в вашем случае, следует учитывать, что вы не можете включить формирование запросов в ваш класс работы с бд (получение и отправка данных в бд), запросы, так как это расширит ваш класс, и создаст ему необходимость работы с другими функциями, а так же сделает интерфейс "толстым". В таких случаях подключаются принципы I. и D.

Comment: @Monomax, т.е. лучше много интерфейсов, для того чтобы в любой момент мы могли либо что-то добавить , или что-то убрать и нам не приходилось бы переделывать много кода?

Comment: в том числе, кроме того множество интерфейсов, предполагают возможность обращаться к ним как сущности.

Comment: Собственно, для таких случаев очень удобно использовать паттерны проектирования.

Comment: @Monomax ну я пока что использовал только стратегию и синглтон)

Comment: посмотрите в сторону строитель/фабрика

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически все так, но задачи бывают разные. Сначала проектируется все правильно, с разделением функций и уровней. А потом оказывается, что для решения задачи разные уровни должны иметь доступ к данным других уровней. И начинается либо перепроектирование, либо построение костылей.

Answer (score 1):

Если класс работает с базой данных, то по принципу единственной ответственности он ничего другого делать не должен. Пусть с БД работает один класс, а с файлами - другой. Если их действия похожи (ну там сохранение, чтение, удаление данных), можете сделать интерфейс и реализовать его в этих классах. Также не поддавайтесь соблазну делать в вашем классе функции с какими-то дополнительными проверками, иначе он сильно разрастется и будет не круто. Эти проверки должны быть уровнем выше, там, где вы этот класс используете (а не внутри него).